# WebApp from localhost to domain

Tags: geoserver, migration

Starting off I've set up Apache Tomcat as my server , and used GeoServer for my data.
Now I want to get my data from localhost:8080 to my domain. Does anyone know how to do that. Any ideas or any references to documentation ?

Comment: copy across your data directory

Comment: Do I need to change anything to GeoServer or Tomcat config ? Or to my code ?